# postgres: constraint check and null values

Tags: database, postgresql, constraints

please have a look at the following table:

```
   name  |  x  |  y
---------+-----+------
   foo   |  3  |  5
   bar   | 45  | 99 
  foobar | 88  | 
  barfoo |  0  | 45
```

I want to add a constraint CHECK ( y > x ), but this obviously will fail due it is violated by the row 'foobar'.

How do I create a constraint that says: check (y > x), but only if y not null?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In fact, you don't really need to do anything else. A check constraint is satisfied if the check expression evaluates to true or the null value.

Your constraint CHECK ( y > x ) would work as is in your scenario because the row foobar would not violate the constraint since it evaluates to null

Answer (score 4):

You can put an IS NULL test into the CHECK expression, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    name TEXT,
    x INTEGER,
    y INTEGER CHECK (y IS NULL OR y > x)
);
```

(tested on PostgreSQL 8.4)

Comment: This is simply not necessary. Quote from the PostgreSQL manual: *It should be noted that a check constraint is satisfied if the check expression evaluates to true or the null value. Since most expressions will evaluate to the null value if any operand is null, they will not prevent null values in the constrained columns.* (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/ddl-constraints.html)

Comment: It may not be *necessary*, but that doesn't mean it's not better to be explicit about the logic.